# Why Eigen vector dot is slower than manual for loop

Tags: c++, performance, eigen

I'm a newbie for eigen.

I test the eigen's vector dot performance, and found it's slower than manual for loop.

code as below:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  Eigen::VectorXf neu1 = Eigen::VectorXf::Random(100000000);
  std::vector<float> x(100000000);

  for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
    x[i] = neu1[i];

  clock_t t1 = clock();
  float r = 0.0f;
  for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
    r += x[i]*x[i];

  clock_t t2 = clock();
  std::cout<<"time: "<<t2-t1<<std::endl;

  t1 = clock();
  r = neu1.dot(neu1);
  t2 = clock();
  std::cout<<"time: "<<t2-t1<<std::endl;
}
```

The result is:

```
g++ test.cpp -otest -I/usr/local/include/eigen/
time: 1070000
time: 1910000

g++ test.cpp -otest -I/usr/local/include/eigen/ -Ofast -march=native
time: 0
time: 50000
```

And, #define EIGEN_NO_DEBUG seems has no effect.

I thought eigen should be optimized and had no reason slower than for loop.

Did I do something wrong?

Or, how can i optimize the eigen performance?

thx

Comment: Why are you comparing performance with out optimizations enabled? O_ó I think even official eigen docs say it's slow without optimizations. Heck, even standard c++ library can be slow without optimizations.

Comment: @luk32 How to enabled eigen optimizations? thx!

Comment: @Ofey not eigen optimizations, just regular compiler optimizations...

Comment: Corrected. Grammar too hard. @Ofey Not eigen optimizations, compiler optimizations `-O3 -mtune=native -march=native` for startres.

Comment: @luk32 no need for `-mtune` if it is the same as `-march`.

Comment: `#define EIGEN_NO_DEBUG` or simply `NDEBUG`.

Comment: Then update your results, and try what 5gon suggested. It should also help. I think the difference should get smaller.

Comment: @luk32 I tested -Ofast -march=native, eigen is also slower than manual loop

Comment: Please include a full code sample, ready-to-compile. I don't want to sort out missing includes by scouring Eigen documentation.

Comment: Anyways, I fixed up your code, you caught me in a helpful mood. Or in a defensive mood, Eigen is not easily attacked ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not doing anything with the result of the first computation and assign to it afterwards. The first computation is optimized out entirely. You can fix this by printing the value of `r` after the computation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Core>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
  Eigen::VectorXf neu1 = Eigen::VectorXf::Random(100000000);
  std::vector<float> x(100000000);

  for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
    x[i] = neu1[i];

  clock_t t1 = clock();
  float r = 0.0f;
  for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
    r += x[i]*x[i];

  clock_t t2 = clock();
  std::cout<<"time: "<<t2-t1<<std::endl;
  std::cout << r << std::endl;

  t1 = clock();
  r = neu1.dot(neu1);
  t2 = clock();
  std::cout<<"time: "<<t2-t1<<std::endl;  
  std::cout << r << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Here is  a sample run produces:

```
/tmp $ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O3 -std=c++14 bla.cpp
/tmp $ ./a.out 
time: 272958
1.67772e+07
time: 29003
3.29441e+07
```

or

```
/tmp $ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Ofast -std=c++14 bla.cpp
/tmp $ ./a.out 
time: 29953
3.23292e+07
time: 28853
3.29441e+07
```

This change wont make your benchmark much better, but the results wont be horribly wrong anymore.

You still should consider average over multiple runs with different datasets. Also don't generate different test data for every run, because your results wont be reproducible.

Finally, as commented below, the difference in results is likely to be due to overflow and/or round-off error. It is suggested to change to double precision or reduce the length of the arrays and run the test again.

Comment: Thx! At this time, -Ofast -march=native are comparable. But in your result eigen is almost 10 times faster.

Comment: @Ofey Fun fact: this seems to be caused by `Ofast`. I use `O3`. My guess would be that `fast-math` does more harm than good.

Comment: Hmmm... why one result is approx. two times bigger than the other...? Shouldn't both be the same?

Comment: @pmr Uh, no, -ffast-math makes the first version much faster than without -ffast-math (vectorizes).

Comment: @pmr with -O3, the result is same with you

Comment: @MarcGlisse Ah, sure. The performance of the Eigen code stays the same, but the `for-loop` becomes a lot faster with `-ffast-math`.

Comment: I love how no-one cares that the results do not match xD. Well at least it computes fast!

Comment: @luk32 Haha, good point. But that is part of the "non-reproducible" benchmark problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're running into over-optimization: the compiler is smarter than you and optimizes out the loop calculation.

I get these timings on my machine:

```
time: 0
time: 23422
```

If you need to be sure something is read/written to in a benchmark, use `volatile`:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  Eigen::VectorXf neu1 = Eigen::VectorXf::Random(100000000);
  std::vector<float> x(100000000);

  for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
    x[i] = neu1[i];

  clock_t t1 = clock();
  float temp = 0.0f;
  for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
    temp += x[i]*x[i];
  volatile float result = temp;    

  clock_t t2 = clock();
  std::cout<<"time: "<<t2-t1<<std::endl;

  t1 = clock();
  result = neu1.dot(neu1);
  t2 = clock();
  std::cout<<"time: "<<t2-t1<<std::endl;
}
```

Then, timings on my machine become:

```
time: 79060
time: 21542
```

Comment: Thanks. Please specify your compiler flags somewhere in the answer and it's all good ;-)

Comment: I think printing results or checking them against each other for correctness should suffice, and would be a good testing practice as well. Like `if (abs(result1 - result2) > epsilon) { something went wrong }`

Comment: I have used `if (std::getenv("PRINT_RESULTS")) { std::cout << result; }` in the past.  It guarantees that computation of the result is never optimized out of existence even if whole-program analysis is performed, but only introduces negligible run-time overhead (unless you set `PRINT_RESULTS` in the environment).

Comment: Well, the difference amounts to 10⁷... which is about what @pmr has as well... probably overflow of some kind.